# Trying to convert the a webkit gradient to moz: wrong format

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to import the gradient below in this [page](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) ("Import from CSS"):

```
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.25, #ACACAC, color-stop(4, #dfdfdf));
```

but I'm gettin this error:

> Couldn't parse gradient CSS. Please check the format and try again.

Any idea?

Javier

Comment: FWIW: The error message is shown on http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing bracket on your first `color-stop`